# RTP/RTSP start up latency: Would this method help to reduce it, and if yes, why we don't have it

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, rtsp, rtp

This is probably not the best forum for such a specialized question, but at the moment I don't know of a better one (open to suggestions/recommendations).

I work on a video product which for the last 10+ years has been using proprietary communications protocol (DCOM-based) to send the video across the network.  A while ago we recognized the need to standardize and currently are almost at a point of ripping out all that DCOM baggage and replacing it with a fully compliant RTP/RTSP client/server framework.

One thing we noticed during testing over the last few months is that when we switch the client to use RTP/RTSP, there's a noticeable increase in start-up latency. The problem is that it's not us but RTSP.

BEFORE (DCOM): we would send one DCOM command and before that command even returned back to the client, the server would already be sending video. -- total latency 1 RTT

NOW (RTSP): This is the sequence of commands, each one being a separate network request: DESCRIBE, SETUP, SETUP, PLAY (assuming the session has audio and video) -- total of 4 RTTs.

Works as designed - unfortunately it feels like a step backwards because prior user experience was actually better.

Can this be improved? If you stay with the standard, short answer is, NO.  However, my team fully controls our entire RTP/RTSP stack and I've been thinking we could introduce a new RTSP command (without touching any of existing commands so we are still fully inter-operable) as a solution: DESCRIBE_SETUP_PLAY.

We could send this one command, pass in types of streams interested in (typically, there's only one video and 0..1 audio). Response would include the full SDP text, as well as all the port information and just like before, server would start streaming instantly without waiting for anything else from the client.

Would this work? any downside that I may not be seeing? I'm curious why this wasn't considered (or was dropped) from official spec, since latency even in local intranet is definitely noticeable.

Comment: Check out http://doom9.org.  There are plenty of sharp people there that may have the knowledge to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, it is possible according to the [RTSP 1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326#page-28) specification:

> 9.1 Pipelining

A client that supports persistent connections or connectionless mode
MAY "pipeline" its requests (i.e., send multiple requests without
waiting for each response). A server MUST send its responses to those
requests in the same order that the requests were received.

The [RTSP 2.0 draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-mmusic-rfc2326bis-29#section-12) also contains support for pipelining.

However none of the clients/servers I've used implement it AFAIK.

Comment: not quite. SETUP must be made using stream URL, DESCRIBE/PLAY are made using session URL. DESCRIBE response will contain "a=control:..." attributes describing stream portion of the URL. Without DESCRIBE repsonse, SETUP cannot be issued. However, PLAY could probably be pipelined along with SETUP commands, can't think of any interdependencies between those two requests.

Comment: I guess you have a point, that would bring it down to 2 RTTs. Similarly a DESCRIBE_SETUP_PLAY also makes no sense: If you need to describe the session in order to be able to stream *dynamic* content, you can't pipeline the request. And if the content (media types, ports) is static or you have an SDP (as it might be in your previous protocol?), then similarly you don't need to do a DESCRIBE?

Comment: In D_S_P request the client could specify whether it wants video or video with audio (99.9% of the time, that's typically the only thing the client needs). D_S_P response would then include the original SDP so that the client would be able to establish decoder pipeline and them immediately start decoding whatever it is receiving

Comment: What if you only want audio and the channel is video only or vice-versa? You then need a second round trip anyway. Or you want video and you don't support the format or you don't have a decoder capable of decoding the specific codec mode? Or your RTP library doesn't implement the packetisation mode, etc? At some point, you need to have extra round trips in a protocol, otherwise you wouldn't need to create a protocol. My point is that RTSP caters for a whole range of use-cases including multicast, VOD, live, SIP addresses some other ones.

Comment: I guess the start-up latency is highly use-case specific. In VOD, would you care if you wait 200ms instead of 100ms when watching a 2 hour movie? Does one extra RTT make such a difference with RTTs ranging anywhere from a couple of ms to say around 250ms for a Europe to Africa connection. And then you need to add in the jitter buffer (say 100ms) to compensate for network jitter in any case? I guess there are so many factors and it really boils down to your specific use-case. Thanks for the discussion!

Comment: yeah, I work in video surveillance and when events occur, people want their video. And in our use-case scenarios we always have video which may or may not have audio with it and there's always one stream of each, so it's definitely more specific than a generic client/server scenario.